# Using provide in a partial layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to have a partial layout file that store all the config variables.  However, I can't access them when I use `render 'layouts/config'`

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:name), yield(:title)) %></title> 

#:name here is empty

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render "layouts/config" %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

_config.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:name, "Grab") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include a partial use  <%= render :partial=>"layouts/config"%>

I would suggest if you want to have all your config variables at on place then you should create a config.yml file in the config directory and declare all the config variables there. All the config variables declared there will be available throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you place `render "layouts/config"` before your `title` tag it will work. But `provide` may not be doing what you think or want.

The layout is processed in order, so in your example `:name` and `:title` haven't been set before trying to call `full_title`.

This post on Yehuda Katz's blog will help: [Automatic Flushing](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/09/07/automatic-flushing-the-rails-3-1-plan/)

Comment: Then how come when I get the `:title` within the `<%= yield %>` part (i.e. new.html.erb) that comes when I generate the view using `rails controller`, it still works.

Comment: The view template, `new.html.erb` is processed before the layout.